# How do you know which S3 permissions to choose in AWS IAM policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am confused as to how do I know which permissions to grant to Lambda service if I want it to be able to perform HeadBucket action.

Here's what I have in CloudFormation right now, and I just deducted these from the SAM S3ReadBucket policy. But how do I know exactly which permissions are exactly required for this?

This is what I have right now.

```
      Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Sid: AllowHeadOnBucket
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
              - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
              - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
              - 's3:GetLifecycleConfiguration'
```

Comment: By checking cli command reference (which isn't very helpful). In your case you need `ListBucket` but 'some say'(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750738/listbucket-vs-listobjects) it's deprecated so to use `ListObjects`. Have you actually tried with adding headbucket to your policy?

Comment: This is more generic comment to your problem maybe this will atleast give you a heads up https://stackoverflow.com/q/68898175/13126651

Comment: @Riz I did try adding the headbucket to my policy and nothing.

Comment: @Riz can you see in the cli command reference that it says that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the [HeadBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadBucket.html) documentation:

> To use this operation, you must have permissions to perform the s3:ListBucket action.

So you need `s3:ListBucket` on the ARN of your S3 bucket e.g. `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket`.

Comment: Interesting, how did I miss it. I did look at this exact page.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Policy Generator can also be handy to help with these things: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: Except that there you already have to know which actions you need to select. And that's exactly what I didn't know.